# Bootstrap toggle button with <template>

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, toggle

Can someone explain and give me a solution why the bootstrap toggle button works fine when page loads but does not when using template and javascript

This code works on load but the toggle button is a checked button when I click on the button "Add Row":

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myButton">Add Row</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Col 1</th>
                        <th scope="col">Col 2</th>
                        <th scope="col">Col 3</th>
                        <th scope="col">Col 4</th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-width="10"
                                data-height="" data-on=" " data-off=" " data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="warning">
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody">
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col">Test 1</td>
                        <td scope="col">Test 2</td>
                        <td scope="col"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td scope="col">Test 4</td>
                        <td scope="col"><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-width="10"
                                data-height="" data-on=" " data-off=" " data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="warning">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <template id="newRow">
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Test 1</td>
            <td scope="col">Test 2</td>
            <td scope="col"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345" readonly>
            </td>
            <td scope="col">Test 4</td>
            <td scope="col"><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-width="10" data-height=""
                    data-on=" " data-off=" " data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="warning"></td>
        </tr>

    </template>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        function insertNewRow() {
            var template = document.querySelector("#newRow");
            var tbody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");

            var clone;
            var td;

            clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            td = clone.querySelectorAll("td");
            td[0].textContent = "A";
            td[1].textContent = "B";
            td[2].textContent = "C";
            td[3].textContent = "D";
            tbody.appendChild(clone);
        }

    $('#myButton').on('click', insertNewRow)

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', insertNewRow);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone explain and give me a solution why the bootstrap toggle button works fine when page loads but does not when using template and javascript

This code works on load but the toggle button is a checked button when I click on the button "Add Row":

Comment: did you try document.onload event?

Comment: I need the toggle button works on a button event.